# How can I rewrite my Regex loop?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a loop to remove certain lines in a string.

```
private static string RemoveGuidLines(string s)
{
    var result = s;

    foreach (var toRemove in GuidConstraintPartials)
    {
        var regex = new Regex($@"^.*{toRemove}.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        result = regex.Replace(result, "GUID line removed by report generator");
    }

    return result;
}
```

`GuidConstraintPartials` is

```
private static readonly string[] GuidConstraintPartials =
    {
        "DF__User__Support__",
        "DF__Setti__NoteT__",
        "DF__Note__",
        "DF__Actor__IsDeleted__",
        "UQ__Atta__",
        "PK__Applicat__"
    };
```

My sixth sense is telling me that I could probably solve this using a better regex or something rather than this butt-ugly code. Any ideas?

Comment: How many `GuidConstraintPartials` can you have?

Comment: also, would anything that starts with `DF__` will be a GUID to replace ? Could your regex be something like `[A-Z]{2}__\w+` ?

Comment: Is the parameter given to RemoveGuidLines() just a single line string?

Comment: @AlexK. Im not sure. I need to replace the line which contains the partial string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One string collection with probably no more items than the ones listed. Maybe one or two will be added some day.

Comment: @Drutten then you have an answer.

Comment: @AlexK. I know but I don't just want to replace the string but the line that contains the string.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread the RE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I create the pattern from the array and create a single Regex with it. In your case, for example, it is a possible bug to use `toRemove` directly instead of `Regex.Escape(toRemove)`. So I would create a pattern that looks like "DF__WisUser__Support__|DF__NoteSetti__NoteT__|DF__Note__IsHeadNote__...and so on" and use that as the regular expression is also more efficient (only reads DF__ once for any of the first 5 strings, for example).

Code:

```
private static string RemoveGuidLines(string s)
{
    var pattern="^.*("+string.Join("|",GuidConstraintPartials.Select(p=>Regex.Escape(p)))+").*$";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
    result = regex.Replace(s, "GUID line removed by report generator");
    return result;
}
```

Also, it is noteworthy that you can create the regex only once, with RegexOptions.Compiled, and store it statically just as the array.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings you are removing are not using any regular expression special characters, you may want to use `String.IndexOf()` instead of regular expressions.